# Win 2003 STD network adapter always showing DHCP when in static IP configuration, + it loses the DNS settings

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking

I have a server that after the first configuration it was DHCP, now I have added it to our domain and in a static IP, however after a few moments it returns to DHCP but with only some of the IPv4 setting staying the same, It loses DNS for example.

I'm not sure what is causing the problem but all I know is this started to happen after I added it to the domain, 
Would it be a domain policy? or the NIC drivers

Spec; Dell M605 Blade server
Windows 2003 STD SP1
Intel Xeon Quad core
NIC: Dual embedded Broadcom NetXtreme IITM 5708 Gigabit Ethernet NIC w/ TOE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the same problem pop up on Dell/Broadcom combos in the past, you'll want to remove all traces of the driver prior to reinstalling.  In all cases, I've had to replace it with the official Broadcom driver for the card to resolve the problem.

As stated in [kb937056](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937056), follow these steps to resolve the problem:

1. Download and then install the latest version of the network adapter driver on the computer.
2. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
3. Locate and then delete the following registry subkey:
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\Config
4. If your server is a domain controller, go to step 5. (This includes servers that are running Windows Small Business Server 2003.) If your server is not a domain controller, delete the following registry subkeys:
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Adapters\ {GUID}
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces{GUID}
5. Click Start, click Run, type sysdm.cpl, and then click OK.
6. In the Systems Properties dialog box, click the Hardware tab, and then click Device Manager.
7. In Device Manager, expand Network adapters, right-click the network adapter that you want, and then click Uninstall.
8. Restart the computer.

After the computer restarts, the operating system automatically detects the network adapter. If the network adapter is not detected, you may have to manually reinstall the network adapter drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a domain policy you would be seeing this behaviour across more servers.  I'd try updating with the latest NIC drivers available from Dell and/or Broadcom (try Dell first and if it's still a problem try Broadcom).

You probably already know this but after you make the changes press APPLY and OK. :)

Answer (score 0):

Double check it truly is set as static by going in to cmd->run 'netsh'->dump

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem, after much searching glad to come across your post.

However, do not have the config you mention above

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\Config

In \Network\ I have 6 keys. 4 named with hex numbers, 1 named Connections and 1 named Uninstalled.

Help! This is giving me a terrible headache.

Running SBS 2003 Premium.